# Calling an event when triggering an API

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, events

I created a notification Event that I need to trigger within my post API after its completion.

The event Args are:

```
public class OrderCreationEvents : EventArgs
{
   public string PickUpLocation { get; set; }
   public string CustomerId { get; set; }

   public OrderCreationEvents(string _pickUpLocation, string _customerId)
   {
       PickUpLocation = _pickUpLocation;
       CustomerId = _customerId;
   }
}
```

The notification Service interface is:

```
public interface IOrderCreatedService
{
    void OnOrderCreation(object sender, OrderCreationEvents args);
}
```

The Interface's implementation is:

```
public class OrderNotificationService : IOrderCreatedService
{
    private readonly IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;

    public OrderNotificationService(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork)
    {
        _unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
    }

    public async void OnOrderCreation(object sender, OrderCreationEvents args)
    {
        var note = new Notification { CustomerId = args.CustomerId, PickUpLocation = args.PickUpLocation };
        await _unitOfWork.Notifications.Insert(note);
        await _unitOfWork.Save();
    }
}
```

Finally, when I create the post endpoint, I need to trigger this event

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Create(OrderIDTO orderIDTO)
{
    var order = new Order {...};
    await _unitOfWork.Orders.Insert(order);

    //Calling the Notification Service
    var note = new OrderNotificationService(_unitOfWork);
    
    return RedirectToAction("index");
}
```

How do I trigger the OnOrderCreation mehtod inside the Create endpoint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I not 100% sure if i got what you want. but i think you do not want to use events. simply you can call the OnOrderCreation method like this:

```
var note = new OrderNotificationService(_unitOfWork);
await note.OnOrderCreation(this, new OrderCreationEvents {.....})
```

Answer (score 1):

You also can follow **Notification** with **MediatR** which is really easy to use and understand.

This [**Link**](https://jonhilton.net/2016/08/31/how-to-easily-extend-your-app-using-mediatr-notifications/) Can help to implement MediatR notification in your controller.

But, if you want to use MediatR notification in your scenario follow this:

```
public class OrderNotification : IAsyncNotification
{
    public string PickUpLocation { get; set; }
    public string CustomerId { get; set; }
}

public  class OrderNotificationService : IAsyncNotificationHandler<OrderNotification>
{
    private readonly IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;

    public OrderNotificationService(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork)
    {
        _unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
    }

    public async Task Handle(OrderNotification notification)
    {
        var note = new Notification { CustomerId = notification.CustomerId, PickUpLocation = notification.PickUpLocation };
        await _unitOfWork.Notifications.Insert(note);
        await _unitOfWork.Save();
    }
}
```

And this would be your controller :

```
private IMediator _mediator;
public constructor(IMediator mediator)
{
    _mediator = mediator;
}

[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Create(OrderIDTO orderIDTO)
{
    var order = new Order { ...};
    await _unitOfWork.Orders.Insert(order);
     
    var note = new OrderNotification
    {
        CustomerId = order.CustomerId,
        PickUpLocation = order.PickUpLocation
    };

    await _mediator.PublishAsync(note);

    return RedirectToAction("index");
}
```

Remember before this, you need to install and setup the packages:

Assuming you have created an ASP.Net Core project in Visual Studio, the next step is installing the following NuGet packages.

1. `MediatR`
2. `MediatR.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection`

To do that, you can either use the `NuGet Package Manager` or the `NuGet Package Manager Console`.

**now Configure MediatR in ASP.Net Core**

Once the two packages mentioned in the earlier section have been successfully installed in your project, the next step is to configure MediatR in the **Startup** class. To do this, you should write the following code in the **ConfigureServices** method. Note that the **ConfigureServices** method is used to add services at runtime to the container.

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
 {
  services.AddMediatR(typeof(Startup));
  services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion
  (CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
 }
```

Comment: what is IAsyncNotification?

Comment: This interface defines your notification messages like EventArgs

Comment: Thank you so much, I will try using it

Comment: Good.give me an upvote please if it was usefull for you